# Why can't I connect OUTER JOIN tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table of teachers and each teacher can also be a principal.
I have to introduce a certain teacher and all his principals.
He does it well for me in this code:

```
   WITH teacherTablecte AS
   (SELECT teacher.IdTeacher, teacher.FirstName, teacher.LastName, 
   teacher.PhoneNumber,teacher.ManagerId, 1 as 'EmpLevel', boss.[FirstName]+' 
   '+boss.LastName  as bossName
   FROM [dbo].[T_Teachers]  teacher JOIN  [dbo].[T_Teachers] boss
   ON teacher.ManagerId = boss.IdTeacher
   WHERE teacher.IdTeacher =2011
   UNION ALL
   SELECT teacher.IdTeacher, teacher.FirstName, teacher.LastName, 
   teacher.PhoneNumber,teacher.ManagerId, teacherTablecte.EmpLevel + 1, boss. 
   [FirstName]+' '+boss.LastName 
   FROM  [dbo].[T_Teachers] teacher 
   JOIN teacherTablecte
   ON teacher.IdTeacher = teacherTablecte.ManagerId  JOIN [dbo].[T_Teachers] 
   boss on 
   teacher.MANAGERID= boss.IdTeacher
   )
   SELECT *
   FROM teacherTablecte
```

But he does not introduce me to the Chief Executive
I tried to convert

```
   WITH teacherTablecte AS
  (SELECT teacher.IdTeacher, teacher.FirstName, teacher.LastName, 
  teacher.PhoneNumber,teacher.ManagerId, 1 as 'EmpLevel', boss.[FirstName]+' 
  '+boss.LastName  as 
  bossName
  FROM [dbo].[T_Teachers]  teacher JOIN  [dbo].[T_Teachers] boss
  ON teacher.ManagerId = boss.IdTeacher
  WHERE teacher.IdTeacher =2011
  UNION ALL
  SELECT teacher.IdTeacher, teacher.FirstName, teacher.LastName, 
  teacher.PhoneNumber,teacher.ManagerId, teacherTablecte.EmpLevel + 1, boss. 
  [FirstName]+' 
  '+boss.LastName 
  FROM  [dbo].[T_Teachers] teacher 
  JOIN teacherTablecte
  ON teacher.IdTeacher = teacherTablecte.ManagerId  OUTER JOIN [dbo]. 
  [T_Teachers] boss on 
  teacher.MANAGERID= boss.IdTeacher
    )
     SELECT *
     FROM teacherTablecte
```

but the JOIN to OUTER JOIN but I get this error:  Msg 462, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Outer join is not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'teacherTablecte'.

Comment: The error message is quite clear.  I would suggest that you delete this question.  Ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: There's a reason a an rCTE can't it used with an `OUTER JOIN`, it could loop indefinitely. I suspect your `OUTER JOIN` should be in the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: See this article [here](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/) on using recursive CTEs

Comment: @Larnu Explain why: it could loop indefinitely

Comment: Because a rCTE stops looping when no rows are returned. If you have an `OUTER JOIN`, then there's the chance that rows will always be returned, so the loop will never end.